# Using request.session to populate a django form

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to save a form in session so that a user doesn't have to reapply filters when going to a different url.  Here is the error I'm getting:

> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

This is the code I have:

views.py

```
def someview(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Form(request.POST, initial=request.session.get('save_form', None))

    if form.is_valid():
      clean_form = json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
      request.session['save_form'] = clean_form

    else:
      pass    
  else:
    form = Form()
```

forms.py

```
class Form(forms.Form):
  startdate = forms.DateField(
      label='Start date',
      initial= '2018-01-01', 
      widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})
  )
  enddate = forms.DateField(
    label='End date', 
    initial= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1), 
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})
  )
  manager = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
      required=False,
      choices=managers,
      widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
  )
```

Being a beginner in Django, I'm not sure where to go from here.  I'm pretty sure the error is in the initial argument.  But, printing it, it seems print what I would expect.

TIA

Comment: Try `form = Form(request.POST or None,` and also, you have to decode the json from the session before passing it as initial...

Comment: Could you please paste the entire traceback? There are a few things that could cause this error, and it's hard to see where it's coming from. Also, are you on Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you JSONfify the form values (`json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, ...)`), but you do not un-JSONify it when reloading from the session.

When reading the session you need to do `json.loads(...)` at some point:

`saved_form = json.loads(request.session.get('save_form', ''))`

The default value `''` might not be the best, I haven't tried. If that's giving you an error, you might want to try replacing it with `{}`.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Note that loading content from the session should probably be done in the last else branch. You generally don't want to provide an initial value when the user is sending data, like in a `POST` request:

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            clean_form = json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, default=str)
            request.session['save_form'] = clean_form
        else:
            pass
    else:
        saved_form = json.loads(request.session.get('save_form', ''))
        form = Form(initial=saved_form)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Generally, what you want to do in a form view is often very similar, and you might find yourself repeating the same boilerplate. Luckily, Django has something to help with that, and it called class-based views, and I recommend [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk/) if you're interested to dive into that, for example [FormView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/).

However, they can be a bit confusing and hard to get your head around when you're just starting. Maybe better to stick with function-based views (as you do) for now, but I thought I linked to these 2 resources which I wish I had when I started learning class-based views.

Comment: Okay.  This worked to clear up the error.  Thank you!  Now, it doesn't work when I refresh.  Request.session has the correct values on the next page, but it's not using it in the form.  I'm starting to think it's in the else:  form = Form() of the code.  Since it's not posting data when i'm going to a different url, that's what it would be pulling.

Comment: I've elaborated on my answer with more content. Just a more "meta" note that if you find an answer helpful, it's good practice on Stackoverflow to upvote it by clicking on the arrow up next to it. Also, when you're asking the question, don't forget to "accept" the best answer. (Sorry if I'm explaining something you already know, but your profile seems new).